# Bitmap exceeds VM budget while rotating image

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm  trying to rotate a bitmap several times on user click. My rotateBitmap function always return a new Bitmap that I save on a in memory Bitmap. In order to can recycle bitmap, I've got two diferent Bitmap variables, I store Bitmap in one while I recycle other.

Nevertheless, I'm getting an OutOfMemorError (bitmap size exceeds VM budget) after some rotations. What I'm doing wrong? Why recycling is not working here?

Here is my code:

```
    private Bitmap myBitmap, myBitmap2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("", "Estamos en oncreate");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rotate);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    super.setUpActionBar(getResources().getString(
            R.string.title_activity_detalle_producto));
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rotate_image);
    imageURI = getIntent().getStringExtra(SELECTEDIMAGEURI);
    rotatedImageURI = getIntent().getStringExtra(ROTATEDIMAGEURI);
    File imgFile = new File(imageURI);
    if (imgFile.exists()) {
        myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
        image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }
}

public void rotateLeft(View v) {
    if(myBitmap!=null){
        myBitmap2 = rotateBitmap(myBitmap, -90);
        image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap2);
        myBitmap.recycle();
        myBitmap = null;
    }else {
        myBitmap = rotateBitmap(myBitmap2, -90);
        image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        myBitmap2.recycle();
        myBitmap2=null;
    }

}

public void rotateRight(View v) {
    if(myBitmap!=null){
        myBitmap2 = rotateBitmap(myBitmap, 90);
        image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap2);
        myBitmap.recycle();
        myBitmap = null;
    }else {
        myBitmap = rotateBitmap(myBitmap2, 90);
        image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        myBitmap2.recycle();
        myBitmap2=null;
    }

}

public void done(View v) {
    saveToSD(myBitmap, rotatedImageURI);
    // finish();
}

public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap source, int angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(),
            source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

This is my stacktrace:

```
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2154)
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2149)
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    ... 11 more
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:444)
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at com.zonaapp.imoments.RotateActivity.rotateBitmap(RotateActivity.java:93)
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    at com.zonaapp.imoments.RotateActivity.rotateRight(RotateActivity.java:77)
06-12 08:57:03.620: E/AndroidRuntime(20121):    ... 14 more
06-12 08:57:03.625: E/(2704): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Comment: A stacktrace always helps

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are two goals here. 1) Display the image rotating every time the user taps on the image, and 2) Save a completely rotated bitmap to disk to be able to send off to a printer later. Currently you are trying to accomplish both tasks together, but that may not be the best approach here. A good reason to use the built in Animation classes (and possibly the reason you are gettting OOM) is that whenever you call [Bitmap.recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29), it is just a suggestion to the Garbage Collector, but it is still up to the GC to get around to freeing that memory. If you are doing multiple rotations fairly close together you could easily get OOM. If this is correct then the faster you tap the more likely you are to get OOM and the slower you tap the less likely you are to get OOM.

You should look into using Androids [built in Animation classes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) such as [Value Animator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html) to animate the rotation value of the ImageView. If you want to ensure backwards compatibility with animations it is good to look into using [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/).

You don't need to, and will not want to keep two versions of this bitmap in memory. Also if the bitmap is unneccesarily large you could look at downscaling it to a proper size. A good reference for working with bitmaps in Android is https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: I need to keep original size of image. I'm doing image manipulation to send it to a printer. So, I really need to get a bitmap rotated, not only show it rotated to user.

Comment: rotations is not allowed in my Activity. I want to rotate bitmap (in order to save it).

Comment: Hmm okay I keep misreading your question. I would still try to go with the animation classes to perform the on screen animation, and have the sending off of the rotated bitmap to the printer be a separate task.

Comment: I can do it, but the problem is while rotating real image (bitmap). Animations doesn't solve problem.

Comment: The problem is not necessarily rotating the real image, but the fact that you don't have enough memory to rotate the real image. By allowing the library classes to perform the animation for you, the memory management will be better than a bunch of successive calls to Bitmap.recycle(), and you should have enough memory to rotate the real image when you need to.

Comment: I could show an scaled image and rotate it with Animator. But the fact is I need original image being rotated and saved on SDCard (even if that Bitmap is not being showed). I think Animations is not useful here.

Comment: You won't be able to save the image to disk if you don't have enough memory, and you won't have enough memory if you try to manually perform rapid animations with Bitmap.recycle(). So you won't be able to save the image to disk if you don't use Animations, thus Animations are useful here.

Comment: Also without seeing the rest of the code I'm not sure how/when you are calling these methods rotateLeft()/rotateRight()/done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55528/discussion-between-yiati-and-pozuelog).